# How do I take over unallocated space on a flash drive with gparted?

Tags: usb, gparted, unallocated

If one have an unallocated space in a flash drive, like this:

[image]

How does one get rid of it, using Gparted?

Comment: You don't have unallocated space (except for a small reserved chunk at the beginning of the drive), all you have is a NTFS partition filling almost all the drive and that partition has unused space (different from unallocated). So... What do you really want to do? That is, if you understand what you're asking, it doesn't seem so.

Comment: And yet appears as unallocated. All of my USB flash drives doesn't show unused or unallocated space at the beginning. I thought it was a brand thing, as other Kingston USB I have showed this, but I have a third Kingston that doesn't. And of all of my Sandisk USB flash drives, none appears like this in Gparted. I thought about deleting the main partition and adding a new partition in that unallocated space, but I'm doubtful about the results, that's why I'm asked. And of all my searches, none have returned anything about Gparted and unallocated spaces in USB flash drives.

Comment: I mean, none of my USB flash drives showed a thing like this (well, almost none)

Comment: USB flash drives don't usually come formated as NTFS either. All I've seen come factory formated as FAT312 so this one may have been already changed. If it was used as a bootable recovery or installation drive for Windows that would explain the unallocated space in the beginning: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg441289.aspx . Antway you should be able to remove the NTFS partition and create one or more partitions of the size and type of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

The allocated space at the front of the drive was created when the NTFS partition was created... and the partition was **aligned** to a cylinder or MiB boundry. **Partition alignment** is important for performance reasons. That being said, you wouldn't normally place a NTFS partition on a USB flash drive, but on a SSD or HDD, and where partition alignment and performance become more important issues.